# AWS IoT MQTT over Websocket with STS temporary credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, mqtt, aws-iot

I am having issues using the temporary credentials to initiate a connection to AWS IoT using STS temporary credentials, whilst keeping things secure.

I have already successfully connected embedded devices using certificates with policies.
But when I come to try connecting via the browser, using a pre-signed URL, I have hit a stumbling block.

Below is a code snippet from a Lambda function which first authenticates the request (not shown), and then builds the url using STS credentials via assumeRole.

Using my generated URL along with Paho javascript client, I have been successful up to the point of receiving a response of "101 Switching Protocols" in the browser. But the connection is terminated instead of switching to websockets.

Any help or guidance anyone out there can provide me with would be much appreciated.

```
const iot = new AWS.Iot();
const sts = new AWS.STS({region: 'eu-west-1'});
const params = {
    DurationSeconds: 3600,
    ExternalId: displayId,
    Policy: JSON.stringify(
        {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "iot:*"
                    ],
                    "Resource": [
                        "*"
                    ]
                },
                /*{
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "iot:Connect"
                    ],
                    "Resource": [
                        "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:ACCID:client/" + display._id
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "iot:Receive"
                    ],
                    "Resource": [
                        "*"
                    ]
                }*/
            ]
        }
    ),
    RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::ACCID:role/iot_websocket_url_role",
    RoleSessionName: displayId + '-' + Date.now()
};

sts.assumeRole(params, function(err, stsData) {
    if (err) {
        fail(err, db);
        return;
    }
    console.log(stsData);

    const AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT_HOST = 'REDACTED.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';

    var url = v4.createPresignedURL(
        'GET',
        AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT_HOST,
        '/mqtt',
        'iotdata',
        crypto.createHash('sha256').update('', 'utf8').digest('hex'),
        {
            key: stsData.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            secret: stsData.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
            protocol: 'wss',
            expires: 3600,
            region: 'eu-west-1'
        }
    );
    url += '&X-Amz-Security-Token=' + encodeURIComponent(stsData.Credentials.SessionToken);
    console.log(url);

    context.succeed({url: url});
});
```

Edit: If it helps, I just checked inside the "Frames" window in Chrome debugger, after selecting the request which returns a 101 code. It shows a single frame: "Binary Frame (Opcode 2, mask)".

Does this Opcode refer to MQTT control code 2 AKA "CONNACK"? I am not an expert at MQTT (yet!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised my mistake by reading the docs on STS.

> If you pass a policy to this operation, the temporary security credentials that are returned by the operation have the permissions that are allowed by both the access policy of the role that is being assumed, and the policy that you pass.

The RoleARN that is supplied must also allow the actions that you are requesting via STS assumeRole.

i.e. The RoleARN could allow iot:*, then when you assume role, you can narrow the permissions down to, for instance iot:Connect and for specific resources.